# Name of a fantasy book a red-haired male protagonist who accomplishes impossible tasks

Tags: story-identification, novel

When I was a kid I read a book as described above. From what I recall one of the tasks was cutting through a thorn forest in order to build an unassailable castle. It turned out he was an orphan of a magical race/family. Can anyone assist with the title of the book please?

Comment: When were you a kid? Where was this? What language? Paperback or hardback? Was it in the kid's section, the adult section, teens? And do you remember who assigned him those tasks?

Comment: Any extra details you can remember will flesh the search out.

Comment: Are you getting mixed up with Harry Potter?

Comment: Other than the orphan thing, what does that have to do with Harry Potter?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Red hair, orphan, magic castle, set of difficult tasks, dangerous forest, magical family. Loads of these tropes match Harry Potter and the Triwizard Tournament.